# Escape key for Safari using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver (Java) and ran into a problem.

I made the method,

```
    public void escape() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
    }
```

but it does not work for Safari. It works for all other browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) except Safari. What will be the alternate escape method for Safari using selenium?

Comment: Try using Java's Robot class as `Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);`

Comment: @mk08 That does not work for me : (

Comment: Oh, it indeed worked for me. It stopped loading the page after Escape key.  Am using Safari 5.1.7.